# Qt Creator Release and Debug same filesize

Tags: qt, debugging, release, filesize

The binary filesize in my release-build is equal to the debug-build of my Qt-Project and the release file is also debugging. I'm using no `CMake` file but I'm changing the build option in the Qt-Creator.

What else do I have to do to force the Qt-Creator to make the project without debug-symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what's wrong with my qmake setup. I had to add/modify the following lines in my environment file:

1. remove -g flags in environment (the result looks like the following lines)

   export CFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -feliminate-unused-debug-types"

   export CXXFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
2. add strip

   export OE_QMAKE_STRIP=arm-......-linux-gnueabi-strip